# How do you keep track of dependant asynchronous tasks?

Tags: android, google-maps, asynchronous

I'm making an Android Application at the moment using MVC. I'm using an Activity as a Controller and a different class as the View.

The View is waiting for two asynchronous tasks, a Google Map and a task sent to fetch data from a database. The View needs the data from the database to place a marker on the map. If the map loads first the we can't place the marker. If the database task finishes then we needs to wait for the map to load.

How do I check that the dependant tasks are finished?
Should I just have a flag to say if the db task is finished and then when the map loads check this to continue and vice versa for the map.
Or is there a better way to do all this.

This is a simplified version of the View:

```
public class SellerAddView 
implements OnChangeListener<Model>, OnMapReadyCallback{
...
public SellerAddView(View view, Model model, Activity activity){

    model.addListener(this);

    mapFragment = ((MapFragment)activity.getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.add_map));
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    LatLng coords = model.getLatLng();
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coords));

}


@Override
public void onChange(SellerAddModel model) { 
    updateView();
}

}
```

Here is the simplified Controller:

```
public class Controller extends Activity{

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View screenView = View.inflate(this, activity_seller_add, null);

    model = new Model();
    view = new view(screenView, model, this);
    populateModel();
    setContentView(screenView);

}


public void populateModel(){
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (model) {
                Model newModel = new ModelDao().getId(id);
                model.consume(model);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: As long as the mapFragment is non null you can add a marker to it.  I wouldn't recomend you program MVC in anrdoid because you'll have trouble getting help.

Comment: You can try to use `AsyncTask` class to try to fetch the data form the database and there is a inner class called `AsyncTask.Status` to check the whether it finish or not. Or just put a `splash screen` to wait for all data to be loaded, that will be better.

Comment: @bjiang I think I'll go with the splash screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can use the `Splash screen` to wait for all data to be loaded, that will be better.

Sample code as following:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static int SPLASH_DELEY = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DELEY);
    }
}
```

And for `activity_splash_screen.xml` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bjiang.map_ex.SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_file"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```